# What's the best way to debug Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, debugging, xdebug

In my normal projects, I use xdebug with phpstorm and it's great; I have no problem with it. However, in Magento2, using xdebug on my localhost is not possible because when xdebug remote is enabled in php.ini, Magento2 takes 1-2mins to load a page. It's totally frustrating.

Disabling the xdebug extension in php.ini will immediately increase the page load to about  5-10secs. Still slow, but better than minutes.

I've now resorted to print_r and logger everywhere in my code. But this is incredibly painful! More so when Magento reports that the error is coming from some factory which then I have to go in and mess up the core with all my print statements!

I've tried on 2 different computers and they both have the same issue with xdebug. First one is a Windows7 x64 8GB ram on an i5 processor. Second machine is a Windows10 x64 16GB ram on an i7 processor.

What is wrong with debugging Magento2 with xdebug? Ideally, I'd like to use a debugger. How can I fix this? Otherwise, how else can I debug when developing on Magento2?

Comment: You can list your system hardware?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Updated my question with my system specs.

Comment: Do you have all cached disabled?

Comment: @KAndy All my cache are enabled.

Comment: Maybe you use Magento on VirtualBox? 10 secs it's too slow even for enabled xdebug

Comment: @KAndy Will VirtualBox actually be faster or slower? I'm using XAMPP now. Wouldn't this be faster since it actually has all the resources my entire PC can offer?

Comment: I don't have windows to test, but i use virualbox and have match better performance. But from other side on windows you cannot use nfs and default file sharing mechanism is slow. So can you install xhrpof and see with functions is slow

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the best solution, however, its the way I debug stuff on Magento 2.

First of all, switch to Developer mode. You can do this via the console:

`$ php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Magento2 by default install in “default” mode and thats why you dont get the error log at the front-end of the site , that can a viewed at magento error log . You may check the complete details over here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

also, you can modify your `.htaccess`file and remove the dash from the first parameter, which will enable developer mode as well. **DONT FORGET TO CHANGE THIS ONCE YOU GO LIVE**

Whilst in Developer mode, errors are shown to the user, also the logging is more verbose.

Another thing you can do is to go into you `index.php` and add PHP-error reporting lines.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If you're still having troubles, try to rename the `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` in `pub/errors/`.

Hope this helps you a little.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. Sometimes, I don't just want to see error. I want to find out what's the value in certain variables along the flow and a debugger is very helpful for this.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Basically I misunderstood your question then a little. Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: No worries! I'm sure your answer is still going to help others who later come across this question! :)

Comment: That's the spirit. :)

Comment: This link will help you to understand the Magento 2 debugging steps.http://tagvibe.com/magento2/how-to-debug-magento-2-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Debugging for Magento 2.4 ([source](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/magento+2+write+to+debug+log))

```
<?php
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('simple text');
$logger->info('printing array: ' . print_r($myArrayVar, true));
```